# Export from garageband to audacity

Tags: audio, garageband

I want to export ALL the audio tracks from garageband to audacity. I searched on the internet and it is apparently not possible ( here for instance), or better it is possible but one track at time.

It seems so weird that nobody found a workaround or wrote a software which performs this acrion...

So, my questions are:

is it possible to export the whole (ALL TRACKS) garageband project to audacity?
is it possible to export the whole garageband project to any other multi-track recording software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GarageBand is basically a simple version Logic, in a similar way that iPhoto is a simple version of Aperture.

What you want to do is easily done in Logic, and it also has the functionality within it that you probably wouldn't even need to export it to Audacity at all.

You can import anything created in GarageBand directly into Logic.

(if it's something you can't justify buying Logic to do, you could get someone with Logic to export the GarageBand tracks for you)

Comment: Thanks for answering, such apparently simple problems are indeed difficult to solve and you are the firt one who gave me a good answer.